# Plot dual points with one point fixed

Tags: python, matplotlib, random

I'm trying to plot a set of points with a special feature,
first plot 2 points with a random coordinates x and y, in a range from 0 to 200,
[image]
but my problem is how can set this points as fixed or centers, take this center-points and from this points, plot one new point with random coordinates(as pairs of points A-a, B-b, etc), and define the distance that can't be higher than 30 meter or units of distance beetwen this points. To get the points like this
[image]

I add part of my code to make this

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from itertools import product
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
#AP POINTS
###################################################
points_xA=np.random.randint(0,200)
points_yA=np.random.randint(0,200)
points_xB=np.random.randint(0,200)
points_yB=np.random.randint(0,200)

center1=np.array([points_xA,points_yB])
center2=np.array([points_xB,points_yB])

ax.annotate("A",xy=(center1),fontsize=12,bbox={"boxstyle":"circle","color":"orange"})
ax.annotate("B",xy=(center2),fontsize=12,bbox={"boxstyle":"circle","color":"orange"})

#STA POINTS
######################################################
#points_xa=np.random.randint()
#points_ya=np.random.randint()
#points_xb=np.random.randint()
#points_yb=np.random.randint()


######################################################
#LABELS
plt.title('random points')
plt.xlabel('x(m)')
plt.ylabel('y(m)')
plt.xlim(0,210)
plt.ylim(0,210)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: First,  correct this line to say: center1=np.array([points_xA,points_yA]).  Then clarify exactly what the conditions for your new desired point are. Your description is not at all clear.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, few days ago, i have solved this script and i going to share it, if is useful for someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have develop a script that plot points as i wanted, but it have some issues:

1.- The menu or bar where the zoom functions, save image, etc. It disappeared and I can't zoom, which I think would be the most important thing.

2.- The table where is the coordinates of each point, for example, for AP_A it have his STA_A1 o more, depending how many STA's you want( for 3 STA's it would be STA_A1, STA_A2, STA_A3, etc)
but in the table apears as STA_A1, for any STA, in the next image it's more clear
[image]

I hope it will be useful to someone, on the other hand if someone can correct those errors in my code it would be great, I thank to  this community where I have found some solutions on several occasions.

code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from itertools import product
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D


##########################
#RADIOS
radius1=30
#radius2=30


#AP POINTS
###################################################


def setNodos(n,rango=300,n_clientes=6):
    
    listaNodos = []
    
    for i in range(n):
        points_x=np.random.randint(0,rango)
        points_y=np.random.randint(0,rango)
    
        listaNodos.append((np.array([points_x,points_y]),n_clientes))
        
    return listaNodos
    

listaNodos = setNodos(4,300,3)


abc = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

points_x = []
points_y = []
sta_cant = []
points_sta_x = []
points_sta_y = []
sta_names = []
for nodo,n in listaNodos:
    points_x.append(nodo[0])
    points_y.append(nodo[1])
    sta_cant.append(n)

t_data=[]

########################################
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))

ax = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0, 0),colspan=2,rowspan=2)


l=0
sta_n=0
print(listaNodos)
for centerA,sta_n in listaNodos:
    cxA,cyA = centerA
    ax.annotate(abc[l],xy=(centerA),fontsize=12,bbox={"boxstyle":"circle","color":"orange"})
    #RADIO CIRCULO ROJO
    ct1A=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
    circx11,circy12 = radius1*np.cos(ct1A)+cxA, radius1*np.sin(ct1A)+cyA
    plt.plot(circx11, circy12, ls="-",color='red')
    #RELLENO CIRCULO ROJO
    ax= plt.gca()
    t1= plt.Polygon([[i,j] for i, j in zip(circx11,circy12)], color='slategrey', alpha=0.2)
    ax.add_patch(t1)


######################################################
#STA POINTS
######################################################
    r_sta = np.random.randint(0,radius1,size=sta_n)
    tita_sta = np.random.randint(0,359,size=sta_n)
    x_sta = np.round(r_sta*np.cos(tita_sta)+cxA,0)
    y_sta = np.round(r_sta*np.sin(tita_sta)+cyA,0) 
    print(x_sta,y_sta)
    for x,y in zip(x_sta,y_sta):
        #plt.scatter(x,y,c='b',zorder=1000)
        x = np.min((300,np.max((0,int(x)))))
        y = np.min((300,np.max((0,int(y)))))
        ax.annotate(abc[l].lower(),xy=((x,y)),fontsize=10,color='black',
                    bbox={"boxstyle":"circle","color":"steelblue","alpha":0.5},
                   )    
        sta_names.append('STA_%s%i'%(abc[l],l+1))
        points_sta_x.append(x)
        points_sta_y.append(y)
    l+=1
######################################################
#Tabla con coordenadas
plt.xlabel('x(m)')
plt.ylabel('y(m)')
plt.xlim(-10,310)
plt.ylim(-10,310)
ax.grid(True)
plt.title('random points')


t_data.append(points_x+points_sta_x)
t_data.append(points_y+points_sta_y)

print(t_data)
print(sta_n)

collLabels =[('AP_%s'%i) for i in abc[:len(points_x)]]

for name in sta_names:
    collLabels.append(name)    
print(collLabels)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (2, 0),colspan=2,rowspan=1)

table=ax1.table(cellText = t_data, 
                  colLabels=collLabels,
                  rowLabels=('coord_x','coord_y'),
                  bbox=[0,0.3,0.1+0.05*len(collLabels),0.6+0.01*len(collLabels)]
                   ,cellLoc='center',fontsize=30)

plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.axis('OFF')

plt.tight_layout(rect=[0.01, 0.01, 1.0, 1.0])
#######################################################
#LABELS

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.savefig('./salida/escen_random.png')
plt.show()
```